# Creating an image database that I can access in Unity

Tags: c#, html, image, unity-game-engine, url

Okay, so I need a way of accessing a (kind of) database of album covers for a app I'm making. What I'd imagine is that I can use a WWW request to go to the image by the image URL, say, `imagedatabase.com/imageineedtoaccess` and getting the image through `GetImage()`.

The problem is, how can I do this? This is less related to unity and more HTML. I've tried things like searching SoundCloud for the songs album cover, a google drive shared folder, and searching youtube, none of them have worked so it looks like I have to use the tougher way. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Can you please specify what is your question exactly - technically how to get image via http in unity? Or are you looking for suggestion for a database of album covers?

Comment: Are you wanting to create a service providing the album covers, or do you want to access an existing album cover service?

Comment: @Neil well id like to use a pre-existing one, but if it comes down to it I'm prepared to make one myself

Comment: Try the Spotify api https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/object-model/

Comment: Well ive tried soundcloud and youtube, im gonna give this a go. ill let you know how it turned out

Comment: @Neil yeah, it didnt really turn out. i think itd be much easier to create my own database of images that i can access by url.

Comment: Then you will have copyright issues.

Comment: well, how can i search for an image using the spotify api and get the album cover of the first result?

Answer (score 0):

Use Unity's WWW class, its quite simple

```
Texture2D myImage;
IEnumerator GetImage(string url)
{
 var www=new WWW(url);
 yield return www;
 if (www.error!=null) 
   Debug.LogError(www.error);
 else
   myImage=www.texture; // contains texture if url results in jpg/png
}
```

Comment: yeah thats not what i wanna do, i wanna make a online database which holds images i can get using that method

Comment: @LeytonMate yeah well your question is to broad